# Suggesstion for executing a PHP image treatment script

Tags: php, android

I have a [PHP script](http://pastebin.com/f70e3ccf7) that has as input a target image and an image dir to make a treatment.
Wanting to make an Android app, i have thinked about this two ideas:
1- Choose the images in the Android device and send them to the server, the server will make treatments and send the output final image to the device.
Problem: A high amount of data will be sent according to the number of images and their size.
2- Execute the php script locally in the device, but i think that it must have a good CPU and i don't know if Android OS can handle that.

Can you please advice me and propose some ideas/solutions?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is present on the android device, the best solution is probably to have to treatment be done on that android device -- not calling any remote service : as you said, an image can be pretty big, and network connectivity is not always fast nor available.

Generally speaking, you cannot run PHP on android *(well, there are ways to run PHP on android, but the corresponding apps are not installed by default)*, so you'd have to re-code your treatment in JAVA, as an android application.

Comment: And the problem that it's not simple to convert the PHP script code to JAVA. By cons, why not calling an app that can execute php scripts and that can handle them perfectly? But in my app i have to notice that the user MUST install the targetted app.

Comment: It's not *simple* to convert PHP code to JAVA, indeed; but it would be much better for your user than sending big images over the network, or forcing them to install another application *-- I'm myself an Android user ;-)*

Comment: You have reason, but it'll take a huge time to know php language first, to comapre it with JAVA and then start converting. And i don't have time :\. Anyway, i'll proceed like you said, i'll try to convert it to JAVA code if i did not succeed, i have the other alternative(temporarly) is to force the user to install other app.

Comment: Well, have fun :-) *(If you've never done JAVA before, you might find it not that easy... but, really, it's not that hard either ;-) )*

Comment: No, i already made two apps(not calculator :D), one that calls other client (based on SIP protocol) and the other that calculates my car's fuel consumption and takes care with it by noticing me with some useful infos. And here is a new idea that comes to my brain and want to make it. More and more difficult :(. Thank you for helping :).

Comment: Oh, then, you should not have too much difficulties :-) *(still, if it was too easy, there would be no challenge -- and no challenge, no fun)*

Comment: And challenge= TIME. And i really have not that time :(. However, i'll try and re-try. Thank you :).